# Get request to couchDB: query string is too long

Tags: post, get, couchdb, query-string

I'm a couchDB newb and I'm trying to grab a large subset of documents by passing an array of keys.

Example: https://my.db/docs/_all_docs?include_docs=true&key=[long array of keys here]

Turns out my key array is too long so I get 400 bad request returned by Apache.

Is there a way I can do a post to that URL and send the keys as post data??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [POST](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/ddoc/views.html#post--%7Bdb%7D-_design-%7Bddoc%7D-_view-%7Bview%7D) request method with specified list of keys in the body. It was specially designed to resolve problem like you got.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found a more efficient way to structure my apps logic so I don't even need that large request, but I'm sure your solution will come in handy soon.